# Why is shutil.rmtree() so slow?

Tags: python, rm

I went to check how to remove a directory in Python, and was led to use [shutil.rmtree()](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil#shutil.rmtree). It's speed surprised me, as compared to what I'd expect from a `rm --recursive`. Are there faster alternatives, short of using [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess) module?

Comment: How big/deep is your directory ? Do you have a few directories with many files, or very deep hierarchies ?

Comment: @DavidCournapeau: It's a bunch of build directories, so it's quite a deep hieararchy.

Comment: I ended up here because shutil was too slow for my use case. Talking about 10-20 directories each containing ten to fifteen thousands files. Totalling 40 GB of data (most files are text, but some are images or videos). And I have 20 backups that I must delete (800GB of data). For my use case at least, shutil is really too slow.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[The implementation](http://svn.python.org/view/python/branches/release27-maint/Lib/shutil.py?view=markup) does a lot of extra processing:

```
def rmtree(path, ignore_errors=False, onerror=None):
    """Recursively delete a directory tree.

    If ignore_errors is set, errors are ignored; otherwise, if onerror
    is set, it is called to handle the error with arguments (func,
    path, exc_info) where func is os.listdir, os.remove, or os.rmdir;
    path is the argument to that function that caused it to fail; and
    exc_info is a tuple returned by sys.exc_info(). If ignore_errors
    is false and onerror is None, an exception is raised.

    """
    if ignore_errors:
         def onerror(*args):
              pass
    elif onerror is None:
         def onerror(*args):
              raise
    try:
         if os.path.islink(path):
              # symlinks to directories are forbidden, see bug #1669
              raise OSError("Cannot call rmtree on a symbolic link")
    except OSError:
         onerror(os.path.islink, path, sys.exc_info())
         # can't continue even if onerror hook returns
         return
    names = []
    try:
         names = os.listdir(path)
    except os.error, err:
         onerror(os.listdir, path, sys.exc_info())
    for name in names:
         fullname = os.path.join(path, name)
         try:
              mode = os.lstat(fullname).st_mode
         except os.error:
              mode = 0
         if stat.S_ISDIR(mode):
              rmtree(fullname, ignore_errors, onerror)
         else:
             try:
                 os.remove(fullname)
             except os.error, err:
                 onerror(os.remove, fullname, sys.exc_info())
    try:
         os.rmdir(path)
    except os.error:
         onerror(os.rmdir, path, sys.exc_info())
```

Note the `os.path.join()` used to create new filenames; string operations do take time. The `rm(1)` implementation instead uses the `unlinkat(2)` system call, which doesn't do any additional string operations. (And, in fact, saves the kernel from walking through an entire `namei()` just to find the common directory, over and over and over again. The kernel's `dentry` cache is good and useful, but that can still be a fair amount of in-kernel string manipulation and comparisons.) The `rm(1)` utility gets to bypass all that string manipulation, and just use a file descriptor for the directory.

Furthermore, both `rm(1)` and `rmtree()` check the `st_mode` of every file and directory in the tree; but the C implementation does not need to turn every `struct statbuf` into a Python object just to perform a simple integer mask operation. I don't know how long this process takes, but it happens once for every file, directory, pipe, symlink, etc. in the directory tree.

Comment: Forget the string manipulation, it's irrelevant.  The other disk accesses are the speed difference.

Comment: not necessarily - it could be significant if the cache is hot (which is likely if the shutil.rmtree is done on a build tree just after a build).

Comment: This answer explain the why, but it doens't provide alternative.

Comment: @AdrienH, indeed, the alternatives mostly involve "don't do this work in Python if performance is your top concern". Using `rsync` or `perl` can give good results: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/79656/7064

Answer (score 3):

If you care about speed:

```
os.system('rm -fr "%s"' % your_dirname)
```

Apart from that I did not find shutil.rmtree() much slower...of course there is extra overhead on the Python level involved. And apart from that I only believe in such a claim if you provide reasonable numbers.

Comment: By *short of using subprocess module*, I actually meant no external system calls like os.system().

Comment: It depends: Calling os.system() or subprocess can be much slower: If you call it often, the operating system needs to create a lot of processes and finally the python version in shutil will be faster.

Comment: For a directory with about 15,000 small (<10KB) files (and nothing else), it was taking several minutes with no progress. Deleting it the other way was much, much faster.

Answer (score 0):

While I do not know what's wrong, you can try other methods, eg remove all the files and then try the directory

```
for r,d,f in os.walk("path"):
   for files in f:
       os.remove ( os.path.join(r,files) )
   os.removedirs( r )
```

Comment: I thumbed up, however, `os.removedirs ( r )` removes the root and not the empty dirs right?