# Fast recursive folder deletion - calling the right rmdir

Tags: python, windows

*This question is not tied directly to python, but I need working implementation under python32 under windows.*

Starting from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5471261/1149736) I assume that using [`shutil.rmtree()`](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/shutil.html) is *really* slow (I need to delete more than 3M files a day and it takes more than 24 hours) under windows so I wanted to use [`subprocess.call()`](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) and `rmdir`, but since I have cygwin in my `%PATH%` system variable wrong `rmdir` gets called and I'll get this:

```
>>> args = ['rmdir', r'D:\tmp']
>>> subprocess.call(args)
cygwin warning:
  MS-DOS style path detected: D:\tmp
  Preferred POSIX equivalent is: /cygdrive/d/tmp
  CYGWIN environment variable option "nodosfilewarning" turns off this warning.
  Consult the user's guide for more details about POSIX paths:
    http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#using-pathnames
rmdir: failed to remove `D:\\tmp': Directory not empty
1
```

*Note: I know it's required to use `/S /Q` to delete folders recursively.*

How can I ensure that the right `rmdir` is called (like under linux you would use absolute path - `/bin/rm`) preferably **without** using `shell=True`?

Is there alternative utility for that (something like using [`robocopy /MIR`](https://superuser.com/a/459769))?

---

#### Edit: speed comparison

I've tested different methods of deleting *237 GB (255,007,568,228 bytes)* in *1,257,449 Files, 750,251 Folders* using [`Measure-Command`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849910.aspx).

```
+-------------------+-------------+----------+-----------------+
|                   | rmdir /s /q |  shutil  | SHFileOperation |
+-------------------+-------------+----------+-----------------+
| Hours             |           3 |        5 |               6 |
| Minutes           |          26 |       52 |              14 |
| Seconds           |          46 |       13 |              48 |
| TotalMinutes      |         207 |      352 |             375 |
| TotalSeconds      |       12406 |    21134 |           22488 |
| TotalMilliseconds |    12406040 | 21133805 |        22488436 |
+-------------------+-------------+----------+-----------------+
```

*Note: test was run on production server (so results may be affected)*

Comment: If you have cygwin in your path you could always use `rm -rf` instead.

Comment: The error you're getting seems to be related to the directory not being empty. Windows will throw this error if there are files in it. Add the `/s` switch to make it recursive?

Comment: @FatalError unfortunately the script is going to run on several machines and I can't rely on them to have cygwin installed (I could check for cygwin and call cygwin and so on, but I wanted an elegant and simple solution)

Comment: @Tadgh I't doesn't really mater in this case, because the whole point is that invalid `rmdir` (the one from cygwin) get's called, I don't want to build a code that depends on no-one will create file `rmdir.exe` in `cwd` of the process.

Comment: "*I assume that using shutil.rmtree() is really slow*" - Do you assume that, or have you measured it?

Comment: `win32com.shell.shell.SHFileOperation()` is a possibility.

Comment: @Robᵩ I didn't measure it precisely, but when executing python script deleting 3M files took more than 24 hours (although it could be caused by the fact it's being run from Task Scheduler and possibly with lower priority), using Far Manager it took less than 24 hour to delete 9M files. And I found documentation for SHFileOperation on MSDN, but I probably didn't spent enough time digging in `win32com`. If you make answer from it (preferably with minimal example) I'll be happy to accept (unless something better shows up).

Comment: Hopefully someone with better Windows expertise than me will answer and flesh out the SHFileOpertions call. I'm curious: how long does it take to delete the files if you just do 'rd /s' in the CMD prompt?

Comment: @Robᵩ I finally got to measure required times properly, check the results if you are interested.

Answer (score 2):

#### Calling proper `rmdir`

I've came up with an idea of calling manually `cmd.exe /C` directly from `%SYSTEMROOT%\System32` and clearing `env` variables (and it seems to work):

```
def native_rmdir(path):
    ''' Removes directory recursively using native rmdir command
    '''

    # Get path to cmd
    try:
        cmd_path = native_rmdir._cmd_path
    except AttributeError:
        cmd_path = os.path.join(
            os.environ['SYSTEMROOT'] if 'SYSTEMROOT' in os.environ else r'C:\Windows',
            'System32', 'cmd.exe')
        native_rmdir._cmd_path = cmd_path

    # /C - cmd will terminate after command is carried out
    # /S - recursively, 
    args = [cmd_path, '/C', 'rmdir', '/S', '/Q', path]
    subprocess.check_call(args, env={})


native_rmdir(r'D:\tmp\work with spaces')
```

I assume that this will work under any version of windows no matter of system-wide `PATH`, but I would still prefer something more *"elegant"*.

This **will** delete all files it can (it **won't stop** after the first error).

---

#### Using [`SHFileOperation()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762164(v=vs.85).aspx)

It's also possible to use `SHFileOperation()` to do this [[example source]](http://code.activestate.com/lists/python-list/464360/):

```
from win32com.shell import shell, shellcon
shell.SHFileOperation((0, shellcon.FO_DELETE, r'D:\tmp\del', None, shellcon.FOF_NO_UI))
```

This **will stop** after the first error (when I was testing this in my environment this solution tended to be slower than `shutil.rmtree()`, probably because UI was involved somehow).

Comment: This is the solution I would have suggested and I think its elegant enough - you need a specific shell and you call it directly.

Comment: I find your first solution best. `rd` is an internal command and not a binary (external) so naturally `cmd.exe` is the one you have to call for it.

Comment: This was very helpful! Instant at least 50% time reduction from shutil.rmtree(). One important thing to note is that this raises `subprocess.CalledProcessError` if for example some of the files to be deleted are in use by another process.

Answer (score 2):

Use the built-ins `os.walk`, `os.remove` and `os.rmdir`

The main thing to be careful about is Windows paths. Either use `/` as path separators instead of `\`,  or use raw strings.

But it is probably best to use `os.path.normpath` on path names that you e.g. get from the command-line.

In the code that follows, `topdown=False` is *essential*.

```
path = os.path.normpath(path)
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path, topdown=False):
    for f in files:
        os.remove(os.path.join(root, f))
    for d in dirs:
        os.rmdir(os.path.join(root, d))
```

A *possible* speed improvement might be to gather all the file paths in a list, and use that with `multiprocessing.Pool.map()` to delete the files using multiple processes. Afterwards you could then use `os.removedirs` to mop up the empty directories. But this solution might also overwhelm the disk subsystem.

Comment: shell.SHFileOperation((0, shellcon.FO_DELETE, a, None, shellcon.FOF_ALLOWUNDO))

Answer (score 1):

> Yes, I've found this alias, but there's the same issue... If someone created rd.exe (or get's installed anywhere in the PATH variable) it won't work. 
>   It doesn't really mater in this case, because the whole point is that invalid rmdir (the one from cygwin) get's called, I don't want to build a code that depends on no-one will create file rmdir.exe in cwd of the process.

So is is the "anywhere in the path" or the current working directory that's the concern? If it's the cwd, then:

```
 if os.path.exists('rmdir.exe'):
     raise BadPathError("don't run this in an insecure directory")
```

But the underlying problems is that you are allowing this to run from a directory where someone can create `rmdir.exe`. Yes, Windows permissions are weak, but it's not that hard to work around.

Answer (score 0):

As documented [here](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/rmdir.mspx?mfr=true), it seems that `rmdir` has an alias, `rd` . I'm unable to test it, but you could try this.

```
>>> args = ['rd', r'D:\tmp', '/s', '/q']
>>> subprocess.call(args)
```

There might be some restrictions on removing hidden files or system files - again I am unable to test it.

Comment: Yes, I've found this alias, but there's the same issue... If someone created `rd.exe` (or get's installed anywhere in the `PATH` variable) it won't work.

Comment: Possibly I am missing the point, but why would someone create `rd.exe`? I can understand `rmdir` being a problem for users with cygwin installed, but `rd` is not a cygwin command. Is `shutil.rmtree()` really that slow in your circumstance?

Comment: It has to delete more than 3M files a day and on batch that size it takes more than 24 hours.