# Why is shutil.rmtree takes hours to delete a folder sometimes? Any alternatives?

Tags: python, python-3.x, shutil

It seems like a trivial issue but I've noticed lately that the `shutil.rmtree` function is either taking a ridiculously long time (like 6 hours) or is simply blocking the execution of the remaining script.

I have a script that does a bunch of operations but before starting everything else, it deletes this folder called "temp" and waits for 5 minutes, then it does a bunch of operations. I've noticed that recently the script is taking over 6 hours to run instead of the usual 10 minutes. After troubleshooting the issue to looks like the script is getting stuck on the `shutil.rmtree` function which basically blocks further execution of the script. I know the script is logically and programmatically fine but this delay is simply causing a lot of trouble. Below is the sample of the script.

```
import shutil
from pathlib import Path
import os

def delFolder(folderPath):
    try:
        shutil.rmtree(folderPath)
    except:
        pass

def main_func(modulePath):

    modulePath = Path(modulePath)
    # Variable declarations and other stuff
    
    temp_folder = Path.joinpath(modulePath, "tempFolder")
    print("Deleting temp folder....")
    delFolder(temp_folder )
    print("Sleeping for 5 min....")
    time.sleep(5*60)

    # Other script functionality to be executed.

if __name__ == "__main__":
    this_modulePath = os.getcwd()
    main_func(this_modulePath)
```

It takes forever(like over 6 hours) to reach from `Deleting temp folder....` to `Sleeping for 5 min....`. I don't why this is happening with shutil. The folder that I am trying to delete is around 4 GB in size and has many files and subfolders in it and no other program is using any files from the temp folder (except onedrive sync, which shouldn't be an issue)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5470939/why-is-shutil-rmtree-so-slow

Comment: A simple alternative would be `os.system(f"rm -rf {delPath}")`. Double- and triple check if the command is actually what it's supposed to be!

Comment: @gog `rm` doesn't work with windows and using `del` command gives a confirmation prompt

Comment: Note that Windows `del` has /s and /q options.

Comment: @jarmod I prefer using libraries that are not OS-dependent, That's why I used libraries like shutil and pathlib

Comment: Of course, I would too. But earlier you were discussing `rm` and `del` so I was explaining how to avoid the confirmation prompt that you took issue with.

Comment: Okay, Thanks. I might use del command as a last resort.